# Как получить приоритеты потоков?

Tags: linux, c

Есть задача:

> Напишите программу, создающую два-три потока, сообщающую приоритеты
>   этих потоков

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * thread_func(void *arg) {
    int loc_id = * (int *) arg;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("Thread %i is running\n", loc_id);
        sleep(1);
    } 
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    int id1, id2, result;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    struct sched_param param1, param2;
    int priority1, priority2;
    int policy1, policy2;
    int res1, res2;



    id1 = 1; 
    result = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_func, &id1);

    res1 = pthread_getschedparam(thread1, &policy1, &param1);
    priority1 = param1.sched_priority;
    printf("pr1 = %d\n", priority1);

    if (result != 0) {
        perror("Creating the first thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    id2 = 2;
    result = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread_func, &id2);

    res2 = pthread_getschedparam(thread2, &policy2, &param2);
    priority2 = param2.sched_priority;
    printf("pr2 = %d\n", priority2);

    if (result != 0) {
        perror("Creating the second thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    result = pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

    if (result != 0) {
        perror("Joining the first thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    result = pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    if (result != 0) {
        perror("Joining the second thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

С помощью строчек

```
res1 = pthread_getschedparam(thread1, &policy1, &param1);
priority1 = param1.sched_priority;
printf("pr1 = %d\n", priority1);

res2 = pthread_getschedparam(thread2, &policy2, &param2);
priority2 = param2.sched_priority;
printf("pr2 = %d\n", priority2);
```

пытаюсь получить приоритеты первого и второго потока соответственно. Но получаю отрицательные результаты.

Могли бы Вы подсказать, как правильно нужно создать несколько потоков и вывести их приоритеты.

Comment: Коды возврата (`res1`, `result` и проч.) надо проверять **сразу** после вызова функции, а не когда захочется.

Comment: И надо смотреть на значение `policy` - если там `SCHED_OTHER`, то о приоритете потока не может идти речи (должно возвращать 0): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html а если хочется иметь приоритеты, то при создании потока надо задавать атрибут `SCHED_RR`.

Comment: @zed Как можно задать атрибут SCHED_RR при создании потока? Сейчас делаю так `result = pthread_create(&thread1, &attr1, thread_func, &id1); pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr1, SCHED_RR);`

Comment: Атрибут надо настраивать перед созданием потока. Переставьте строчки местами.

Comment: ...а ещё для этого нужен мандат `CAP_SYS_NICE`...

Comment: >>Но получаю отрицательные результаты.<< — что значит «отрицательные»? какие именно результаты получаешь и чем/почему они отличаются от ожидаемых?

Comment: @Fat-Zer получаю отрицательные числа. К сожалению, уже не смогу воспроизвести. На сколько я понял, то приоритет может быть от 1 до 99, поэтому числа типа -2876234 неприемлемы.

Comment: @zed Поменял местами. Теперь сообщение с приоритетом второго потока не выводится. `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` [Листинг программы](https://pastebin.com/9rqN0UrU)

Comment: А [pthread_attr_init](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html) кто будет делать?

Comment: @zed Если задавать приоритеты самому - программа работает. Но можно ли как-то автоматически задавать приоритет при создании потока, а затем просто выводить эти приоритеты? [Листинг работающей программы](https://pastebin.com/n3vMGCSn)